# Show Field onclick of radio button in Vf page using javascript

Tags: javascript, visualforce

[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5TsG.png)

I am unable to show the field on-click of radio button.
Facing the error as :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
I am struggled ,but not yet solved.Please help on this.

Comment: Post some code or a working example and we might be able to.

Comment: As far as i see, the getElementById function doesnt return a valid Element. What does it return?

Comment: I have attached the image and pasting also again.<script type="text/javascript">
            function Disablefilter(var1){
                          alert(var1)//Receiving the var1 here.
                    document.getElementById(var1).style.display = "block";
                        
           }

Comment: There is no element with that id on the page

Comment: I have the element and returining the ID also.Please see the image@Newman